# Add Google Cloud Services (GCS) to kaggle notebook

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kaggle

I recently received $300 worth of credit when when creating a GCP account. However, when I try to connect to it via kaggle notebook *add-ons* feature. I am taken to another google account of mine which I use to log into kaggle from. This account does not have credits since I was unable to use them within the time limit. Could anyone be able to help me in this regard.

Thanks

Michael

Answer (score 2):

1) Check which identity you are using to log in.

2) In the Google Cloud Console window select the project that you have credit for.

3) If you are using the CLI, set up the identity:

```
gcloud auth login
```

4) Setup the correct project:

```
gcloud config set core/project PROJECT_ID
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the motivation. Thanks & Best Regards Michael

Answer (score 1):

I manged to fix it. What you need to do is to go to your kaggle account and unlink what ever google account you have. Then go to the kaggle kernel and in the add-ons tab, press google could services. Then add the account that you desire.

Further information could be found in this question: [Cannot connect Google AutoML to kaggle kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60943173/cannot-connect-google-automl-to-kaggle-kernel)

Thanks & Best Regards

Michael