# Cannot connect Google AutoML to kaggle kernel

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kaggle

I am trying to connect to google cloud services via kaggle notebook. However I am getting a attribute  error on Kaggle notebook.

Please find the code below;

```
PROJECT_ID = 'abc'
from google.cloud import automl_v1beta1 as automl
automl_client = automl.AutoMlClient()
```

error;

```
AttributeError: module 'google.cloud.automl_v1beta1' has no attribute 'AutoMlClient'
```

Would anyone be able to help me regarding this

Thanks & Best Regards

Michael

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code but I did not get errors. I used the same code as you:

```
from google.cloud import automl_v1beta1 as automl


# Create an AutoML client
client = automl.AutoMlClient()
```

Have you installed the library?

```
pip install google-cloud-automl
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. It is already installed in the kaggle notebook when I do `!pip install google-cloud-automl` .Output gives; `Requirement already satisfied: google-cloud-automl in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.10.0)` Thanks & Best Regards. Michael

Comment: Have you set up correctly the Google Cloud Project? Following these steps https://www.kaggle.com/devvret/automl-tables-tutorial-notebook should work.